# How to match files that start with a character in gulp filter?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-rev, gulp-filter

I want to filter the file (vendor.min.js and vendor.min.css) which is starting with vendor  and then add revision to it. How to match the files which start with vendor? I tried to give

```
var filterVendor=filter(['!src/main/^vendor*js']);
var filterVendor=filter(['!src/main/vendor*js']);
var filterVendor=filter(['!src/main/[^vendor]']);
```

I want to filter all the files which start with vendor

```
var filter = require('gulp-filter');        

    var filterVendor=filter(['!src/main/^vendor*js']);

          return gulp.src ( [srcFolder + '/app/*.jsp', srcFolder + '/app/auth/*.jsp'] )
                    .pipe ( assets )
                    .pipe ( $.if ( '*.js' , $.ngAnnotate () ) )
                    .pipe(filterVendor)
                    .pipe( rev() )
                    .pipe($.useref() )
                    .pipe( assets.restore() )
                    .pipe( importFn )
                    .pipe ( gulp.dest ( distFolder ) )
                    .pipe (  $.size ( {'title': 'html'} ) );
            } );
```

I'm new to gulp.If anyone knows please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use regex `[^vendor].js`

Comment: @Justcode  It is filtering all js files

Comment: That may be because you are piping all js with filtervender variable. it would be better if you can add separate rule for it.